# Bibliography error: (re) run Biber on the file

Tags: biblatex

I have used the `biblatex` package and I created a bibliography in a `.bib` file. I've created a link to this file (`\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`) and at the end of my document I've put the `\printbibliography` command.

The bibliography is not shown in the pdf...I receive the following errors:

1. `Empty bibliography on input line ...`
2. `Please (re) run Biber on the file ... and run Latex afterwards.`

Can you explain me why is not working?

Comment: You need to run Biber so that `biblatex` can access the bibliographic data. Maybe you are running BibTeX instead, maybe you are not running a bibliography tool at all. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: Any news here? Could you run Biber on your document? At the moment your question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 and I will vote to close as such in due time if there are no new developments here.

Comment: I voted to close the question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. As the question stands now that is the most probable source of the issue as described. If that running Biber did not work for you, please edit your question with more details of what you tried and how it did not work for you, and ping me so I can vote to re-open your question.